# Sum of dates in dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have 2 dataframes. One with dates of the form: days,month,year and another with days, as shown in the example below.

```
dfdates: 29/12/2020
         24/12/2020
         29/12/2020
         18/12/2020
         17/12/2020
         17/12/2020

dfdays: 60
        60
        25
        25
        60
        25
```

How can I create a new dataframe that is the sum of both dataframes? for example, if I add

```
12/29/2020 + 60
```

the new dataframe:

```
02/27/2021
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `datetime` with `timedelta`:

```
pd.to_datetime(dfdates['date']) + pd.to_timedelta(dfdays['days'], unit='D')
```

Comment: Thank you @Quang Hoang, this help me!